# Custom GREP with asterisks and anchors?

Tags: grep, find, regex

I have lots of EDI files (which is pretty much a single line of gibberish text) that are about 300mb/pcs.

I'm looking to pattern matching this:

```
`*UP*605284466346 {lots of other stuff inbetween with set length} QTY*17`
```

What I know is that UP is at the head of every *section* followed by the *sku*
at the tail end is QTY with the *quantity #*.

What I'm trying to find is *SKU: 605284466346* with a *QTY: 17*

This was my valiant attempt:

`find * | grep -lir 'UP*605284466346.*QTY\*97' * | grep -v svn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` is much better for that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage findsku <SKU> <QTY> <DIR>
# Example: findsku 605284307892 14 ~/mydir
# Result: found ./teste.edi: SKU=605284307892, QTY=14

sku=$1
qty=$2
dir=$3

echo "looking for SKU #${sku} with QTY=${qty} in ${dir}:"

while read -r file; do
    awk -F'*' -v sku="$sku" -v qty="$qty" 'BEGIN{RS="*UP*"} $2==sku &&
    $NF==qty {print "found " FILENAME ": SKU=" sku ", QTY=" qty}' "$file"
done < <(find "$dir" -name "*.edi" -type f)
```

I think it is pretty much self-explanatory, and you can adapt for any sku and qty values you want. But feel free to ask any question you want about it!

It will recurse in the given `DIR`, and you can easily adapt it to scan other files besides `*.edi`

Comment: If this works for ehime, I'll upvote this when I've got more votes.

Comment: It didn't work, I'm not sure if its looking through files or not? Above was a test case so 605284466346 should have 17 but I have zero returns from searching using *.edi?

Comment: ok, but like i said, its a single 300mb line i'll try and cat out a chunk though

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HY4mc4Dq @MestreLion no there are multiple `*UP*` segments, but the entire file is a continuous line, look at the pastebin and you should get a better idea

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3333/discussion-between-ehime-and-mestrelion)

Comment: OK, let me fix my remark -- for clarity, the `-F'*'` in this answer sets field separator to `*`, so this automatically breaks the text into atoms which are separated by the `*`s.   $1 is blank, $2 is "UP", $3 is "605284466346", and so on.

Comment: @belacqua: correct. But the catch is: his whole file is a *single* line, with multiple records! So I had to also set a custom **record separator** using `RS`. That shifted the fields, as UP is not a field anymore, but a separator. So sku is `$2` now